# Why isn't assign on a foreach iteration variable in Array.ForEach an error?

Tags: c#

Given an array of `int` numbers like:

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

If we want to increment every number by 1, the best choice would be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    arr[i]++;
}
```

---

If we try to do it using `foreach`

```
foreach(int n in arr)
{
    n++;
}
```

as expected, we meet the error:

> Cannot assign to 'n' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'

---

Why if we use this approach:

```
Array.ForEach(arr, (n) => {
    n++;
});
```

which is equal to the `foreach` above, visual studio and compiler aren't going to tell us anything, the code is going to compile and just not producing any result in runtime, neither throw an exception?

Comment: `ForEach` is a function and `n` a local variable in a function. This is perfectly valid to do.

Comment: Basically, the compiler can only prevent errors that the language rules tell it about. There's nothing to prevent you from assigning a new value to a parameter in a lambda expression, even if that doesn't do anything useful in your particular case.

Comment: @tkausl: You should post that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(int n in arr)
{
    n++;
}
```

This is a language construct, the compiler knows exactly what a foreach-loop is supposed to do and what `n`is. It can therefore prevent you from changing the iteration variable `n`.

```
Array.ForEach(arr, (n) => {
    n++;
});
```

This is a regular function call passing in a lambda. It is perfectly valid to modify local variables in a function (or lambda), so changing `n` is okay. While the compiler *could* warn you that the increment has no effect as it's never been used afterwards, it's valid code, and just because the function is called `ForEach` and actually does something similar to the foreach-loop doesn't change the fact that this is a regular function and a regular lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Both are two different things.

First we need to be clear what we need. If the requirement is to mutate the existing values then you can use for loop as modifying the values while enumerating the collection shouldn't be done that' why you face error for the first foreach loop.

So one approach could be if mutating is the intention:

```
for(int i=0; i< arr.Length; i++)
{
    arr[i] = arr[i] +1;
}
```

Secondly, If the intention is to get a new collection with the updated values then consider using linq `Select` method which will return a new collection of `int`.

```
var incrementedArray = arr.Select( x=> (x+1));
```

### EDIT:

the key difference is in the first example we are modifying the values of colelction while enumerating it while in lambda syntax `foreach` a delegate is used which get input as local variable.

Comment: I already showed in the question the for version, I wasn't asking a solution about it, but information on why the Array.ForEach wasn't throwing an exception for an illegal instruction

Comment: because as someone already commented it has local variable getting assigned with value

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` statement executes a statement or a block of statements for each element in an instance of the type that implements the `System.Collections.IEnumerable` or `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` interface. You cannot modify iterated value because you are using `System.Collections.IEnumberable` or `System.COllections.Generic.IEnumberable<T>` interfaces which support deferred execution.

If you want to modify value you can also use

```
foreach(ref int n in arr)
{
    n++;
}
```

**Updated**

The `Array.Foreach` is a method that performs specified action on each element of the specified array. This function support immediate execution behavior and can be applied to only data that holds in memory. The `Array.Foreach` method take an array and used `For` loop to iterate through collection.

`foreach` and `Array.Foreach` both looks same but are different in their working.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @tkausl, `n` with `ForEach` is a local variable. Therefore:

```
static void Main()
{
    int[] arr = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ",arr));

    Array.ForEach(arr, (n) => {
        n++;
    });
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ",arr));
}
```

will output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Meaning you **don't change** the values of `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.ForEach` is **not** identical to a `foreach`-loop. It´s an extension-method which will iterate a collection and performs an action on every of its elements.

```
Array.ForEach(arr, (n) => {
    n++;
});
```

however won´t modify the actuzal collection, it will just re-assign a new value to `n` which has no relation to the underlying value in the array, because it´s a value-type which is **copied* to the anonymous method. So whatever you do with the param in your anonymous method isn´t reflected to the `ForEach`-method and thus has no effect in your array. This is why you can do this.

But even if you had an array of reference-types that would work, because you simply re-assign a new instance to the provided parameter, which again has no effect to the underlying array.

Take a look at this simplified example:

```
MyClass
{
    void ForEach(Action<Item> a)
    {
        foreach(var e in myList)
            Action(e);
    }
}
```

In your case the action looks like this:

```
x => x++
```

which simply assigns a new value to `x`. As `x` however is passed **by value**, this won´t have any effect to the calling method and thus to `myList`.